# How do I combine displacement and surface deform?

Tags: modifiers

I have a plane mesh (with high poly count) that looks like this thanks to a displacement modifier:

[image]

Now I would like to deform it so that it lays neatly on a much larger sphere while preserving the geometry of the extruded cubes - sort of in the way a something made of rubber would.

I've tried using a plane shrinkwrapped to the sphere, and then a mesh or surface deform on that but it squishes the cubes down.

How do I get the mesh to deform but keep the variable thickness?

Comment: Maybe you should change the order of modifiers? First shrinkwrapping it and then displacing the surface with the cubes? Depends on how you mapped the displacement onto the surface.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann - thanks, but no good results. Squished though in a different way

Answer (score 1):

would you mind using geometry nodes?

with this node setup:

[image]

you get this:

[image]

Advantages: low poly count, procedural, high performance

Comment: That's really nice (and I will try it) but no. My workflow has a step in which the height and position of the cubes is drawn as colored polys on SVG, and then converted to the relevant grayscale, so that won't work

Comment: ah ok, i understand that. So it might be a good idea to write such an info in the question so that people know what answer makes no sense ;)